# How to monitor list of services on remote machines?

Tags: powershell

I would like to monitor a list of services on remote machines.
These services are not the same on all remote machines.

The closest I have got is to monitor all services which are stopped on remote machines but I cant seem to find a way to script a way to monitor a list of services.

This is script I am working on:

```bsh
$Date = Get-Date -Format dd-MMM-yyyy
$Time = Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss tt"
$Style = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
"@

$ServerList = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\computers1.txt
$body = $ServerList |
        Foreach-Object {
          Get-Service -ComputerName $_ | Where-Object {
            $_.Status -ne "Running" -and
            $_.StartType -like "Automatic"
          }
        } |
        Select-Object MachineName, Status, DisplayName, StartType |
        Sort-Object -Property MachineNAme -Descending |
        ConvertTo-Html

$colorTagTable = @{
  Stopped = ' bgcolor="#ff0000">Stopped<';
  Running = ' bgcolor="#00ff00">Running<'
}

# get possible values look them in text sorrounded by > < and replace
# them with style (pun intended).
$colorTagTable.Keys | foreach {
  $body = $body -replace ">$_<", ($colorTagTable.$_)
}

ConvertTo-Html -Head $Style -Body $body | Out-File "C:\temp\srv.htm"
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx).

> **-ComputerName<String[]>**
>   Gets the services running on the specified computers. The default is the local computer.
>   Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of a remote computer. To specify the local computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or localhost.
>   [...]
>   **-Name<String[]>**
>   Specifies the service names of services to be retrieved. Wildcards are permitted. By default, this cmdlet gets all of the services on the computer.

```
$Style = @"
<style>
...
</style>
"@

$ServiceList = 'NetLogon', 'Spooler', 'W32Time'
$ServerList  = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\computers1.txt

Get-Service -ComputerName $ServerList -Name $ServiceList |
  Select-Object MachineName, Status, DisplayName, StartType |
  Sort-Object -Property MachineNAme -Descending |
  ConvertTo-Html -Head $Style |
  Out-File 'C:\temp\srv.htm'
```

Services that don't exist on a particular computer are ignored unless none of the services is running on that computer, in which case you'll get an error. Run `Get-Service` with the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` if you want to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

for service list I will have something like this to actually get the service which should be running and have email reports instead of logging and checking html pages

```
$servicelist=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "state = 'stopped' and startmode = 'auto'" | select Name


$From = "YourEmail@gmail.com"
$To = "AnotherEmail@YourDomain.com"
$Subject = "Daily Service Report From "
$Body = "get-content C:\temp\srv.htm "
$SMTPServer = "smtp.email.com"
#$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To  -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer #-port $SMTPPort
```